# Can the SSH client affect how long it takes to run some code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ssh, deep-learning, pytorch

I'm running a CNN algorithm on an interpreter which is running on a remote machine. The code is pretty simple and resembles this: https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/blitz/cifar10_tutorial.html

But I added a TensorBoard writer to draw the training and validation loss as well as 3 images per epoch.

I used both PyCharm and MobaXterm to access the remote server (an Amazon AWS EC2 instance). But I've noticed significant performance differences whether I run the code from PyCharm or from MobaXterm with a command line.

The results averaged on 10 iterations.
Pycharm: Each iteration takes 55s.
MobaXterm: Each iteration takes 95s.

I've made sure that both are using the same conda environment and the same Python to run (Python 3.7).

Maybe I'm missing a key comprehension of MobaXterm and working with a remote interpreter?

Comment: Are you outputting a lot of text to the console while running the program?

Comment: No, I'm outputting only a couple of lines before I run the first epoch. However, I use Tensorboard. I added some more information to the question.